# Non-degeneracy of product of group pairings

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

For $G$ finite abelian group, let $\eta,\omega:G \times G \to \mathbb{C}^\times$  be group pairings. What can I say about the (non-)degeneneracy of the product pairing $\eta \cdot \omega$ in terms of the (non-)degeneneracy of $\eta$ and $\omega$? The product is defined elementwise: $(\eta \cdot \omega) (g,h):= \eta(g,h) \cdot \omega(g,h) $.

Comment: What is a group pairing?

Comment: a map $\omega: G \times H \to \mathbb{C}^\times$, s.t. the induced map $G \to H^*$ is a group homomorphism, where $H^*$ is the dual group of $H$

Comment: If product is what I think it is, it's obviously nondegenerate of and only if so are $\mu$ and $\omega$.

Comment: the product is defined elementwise.. I dont see why this is obvious..

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev what kind of product did you think of?

Comment: I thought about the straightforward direct product. (If you want, the direct product of the associated homomorphisms.) If you mean something else, you should define that.

Comment: okay, I edited it

Comment: OK, so you take the direct product and restrict it to the diagonal. Honestly, I think chances are very low to have it nondegenerate. How did you come up with this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but rather a comment with too many characters to post as a comment.

If $A$ is a finite abelian group and $\chi\colon A\to A^*$ is an isomorphism, then $\chi$ determines a group isomorphism between $\langle \textrm{End}(A); +,-,0\rangle$ and the abelian group of pairings under pointwise product. Namely, if $\varphi\in\textrm{End}(A)$, then the corresponding pairing is $(a,b)\mapsto (\chi\circ \varphi(a))(b)$. Under this correpondence the property of nondegeneracy of a pairing corresponds to the property of injectivity of an endomorphism. Since $A$ is finite, nondegenerate pairings correspond to units in $\textrm{End}(A)$.

Hence the main question about pairings (*What can I say about the nondegeneneracy of the product pairing $\eta\cdot\omega$ in terms of the nondegeneneracy of $\eta$ and $\omega$?*) translates into the following question: *When is the sum of two units in the ring $\textrm{End}(A)$ equal to a unit?* Similarly, if you replace *nondegeneracy* with *degeneracy* in the original question, you should replace *unit* with *nonunit* in the reformulated question. Since $\textrm{End}(A)$ is a fairly typical finite ring, these questions are unlikely to have nontrivial answers.